# SQL Server - select column_name from (multiple tables_name stored in a variable)

Tags: sql-server

Let's consider 4 Tables: `[Starter], [Meal], [Dessert], [Drinks]`. I need to check in each table if the column `[Price]` exceed at least one time 15. And retrun the value into the table `[My_table]` to insert the boolean into the row with the table name.

```
 update [DB].[dbo].[My_table]
          set [Check_column]= 
             case when [price] > 15 then 'OK'
             else 'WRONG'
             end
    from @multiple_tables_names
```

I would like to use this update statement for checking the content of the column `[Price]` in multiple tables (which have the same structure).

This would be the table `My_Table`:

```
 [Type] |               [Check_column]
----------------------------------------------------------
Starter |                   OK
-----------------------------------------------------------
Meal    |                  WRONG
-----------------------------------------------------------
Dessert |                    OK
-----------------------------------------------------------
Drinks  |                  WRONG
```

Comment: Do you have a table with the table names to be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is "similar" to next one and table names are stored there:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Type] nvarchar(100),
    [Check_column] nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Type]) VALUES
    ('Starter'), ('Meal'), ('Dessert'), ('Drink');
```

You can dynamically build and execute UPDATE sentences using a CURSOR.

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @type nvarchar(10);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Type] FROM [MyTable];

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Type
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
        SET @cmd = 'update [MyTable]
            set [Check_column] = 
                case when exists(select 1
                                 from   ' + @Type
                              + ' where left([TVF],4) = ''M006'' or left([RPPS],4) = ''1009'')' 
             + ' then ''FAILED'' else ''OK'' end'             
           + ' where [Tabs] = ''' + @Type + '''';

    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Type
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc04feeefc0e206bbea358e187d54de4)*

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

this query is working but not giving me the output I want.

I am expecting to have 'FAILED' when one of the two conditions is met at least one time through the rows in the columns `[TVF]` or `[RPPS]`. But here I have always 'OK' as output in my updated table. Normally, I should have 'FAILED' for the row `[AFUP]` and 'OK' for the row `[BICHATP]`.

Can you run it on your machine?

```
drop table [MyTable]
drop table [BICHATP]
drop table [AFUP]


CREATE TABLE [AFUP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE [BICHATP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO [AFUP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M006', '1010'), ('M054','1000'), ('M015', '2324');

INSERT INTO [BICHATP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M000', '1101'), ('M090','1001'), ('M012', '1023');

CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Tabs] nvarchar(100),
    [Check_column] nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Tabs]) VALUES
    ('AFUP'), ('BICHATP');


DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Tabs nvarchar(10);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Tabs] FROM [MyTable];

OPEN cur1;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'update [MyTable]
                set [Check_column] = 
                    case when left([TVF],4) = ''M006'' or left([RPPS],4) = ''1009'' then ''FAILED''
                         else ''OK''
                    end
               from DB_SANOFI.dbo.' + @Tabs;

    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
END

CLOSE cur1;
DEALLOCATE cur1;

select *
from MyTable
```

Comment: edited https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc04feeefc0e206bbea358e187d54de4